# Answer downvoted after question was edited

Tags: discussion

Recently received my first downvote on one of my answers, but feeling a bit frustrated :)

I answered the original version of the question which was, to be honest, not really detailed. After my answer was posted the question was edited to include more details so my answer became off topic. Received a downvote because of this.

Is there a way to link an answer to a particular version of the question? I removed my answer now, but that doesn't feel right either.

Comment: After going through your profile, I couldn't find any of your question downvoted unless someone else, upvoted it or reverted there downvote, would you like to provide link to question :)

Comment: It's this one: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60504/spdiag-3-0-filling-up-wss-logging-db I deleted my answer, so that's probably why the downvote is not visible in my profile

Comment: @TimeToShine You need 10k rep to see deleted posts (unless it's your post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes this stuff happens. You can't please everybody; you do your best, but somebody doesn't like what you wrote for whatever reason. It's just not worth worrying about.

The more common case is where you answer a question and the OP then changes the question, thus pulling the rug from under your answer. Then the only thing you can do is add a comment or edit if you notice this has happened, which is fortunately only on rare occasions.

Answer (score 1):

There could also be an unfortunate coincidence where a user  tries to get the [Critic Badge](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/badges/7/critic) for the first downvote. On general I don't care of downvotes that isn't followed by a comment (which I believe is an unwritten rule at *.SE). But if you get a comment with the downvote you could act on it either in comment or by editing your post.

Comment: sorry to have to say this... but about the unwritten rule... I would disagree about that. Do not think that everybody will leave a comment - actually most users do not belive they should "do the work" of leaving a comment - they have already lost some time for downvoting and are entitled to just do that, without need to explain. IMHO that defeat the whole purpose of voting for CORRECTING errors, but seems the mainstream vision is just that. So, do not get angry if you will receive unexplained -1 - it is "normal".

Comment: See all the discussion on main meta: [Having a way to anonymously contact a downvoter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166751/having-a-way-to-anonymously-contact-a-downvoter#comment488586_166751), [Allow users to leave an anonymous comment when voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/allow-users-to-leave-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting/98863#comment480484_98863), [Feature request: @Downvoter sends a notification to all downvoters for your post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/feature-request-downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post)

Comment: And also [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

Comment: @SPArchaeologist That's interesting. On UX.SE there is almost a pursuit on users who didn't comment a downvote. Especially if it's hard to know why since a post may be accurate and reasonable but not to the liking of the downvoter. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Benny, you don't know hou much I envy that. As I said on one of the linked topics (an answer that I have since deleted, because it seemed that it wasn't really understood or else) I somehow fear random downvotes on SharePoint related question. The "It is wrong, but I won't tell why" approach somepeople are so proud of IMHO is totally nosense. I have already explained my point of view... there are some --really-- dangerous error you can do on SP development, and if the downvoter belive he don't have to explain he can keep his downvote too. No need for noise, no need for random -1s.

Comment: Also consider that if you don't have/don't use the split vote view, downvote on a total score above 0 are **invisible**, so without explanation they won't do any good to any unregistered user. That means that the vote fails both at signaling answer quality and at providing an incentive to fix bad content. Again, that my be only my point of view (wich is the point of view of a lone swordman that cross the seas on a coffin used like a boat, so count me in the "mad hatters" club..) but as of today still thinking that way. Moral: it is dangerous to go alone, take this advice.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I'm happy to take advice from more experienced users, thanks!

Comment: Don't worry, no need for thanks. Just sharing what I learned from the main meta site. Anyway, to return to the original topic - you may be right about the badge... but IF that was my only target I would downvote a question (== GRATIS) and not an answer (== -1).